# How to write a specific logger in a file with Log4J 2.X ? (progammaticaly in JAVA)

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm upgrading a code from Log4j 1.X to Log4J 2.X.

I'd like to write a specific logger in a file using Log4j 2.X. I tried some code found on Log4j website but I can't seem to find any code that does the same.

Log4j 1.X code :

```
    Logger LOCAL_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
    
    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("mylayoutpattern");
    String logFile = "myFile";
    
    FileAppender app = new FileAppender(layout, logFile, true);
    
    LOCAL_LOGGER.addAppender(app);
    LOCAL_LOGGER.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Log4j 2.x two main changes were introduced that concern your code:

- the library was split into an API part and a standard implementation part.  The API interface `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` that is returned from calls to [`LogManager.getLogger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html#getLogger--) is not concerned with layout and appenders. However if you are sure the underlying implementation is Log4j2 Core, you can cast it to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger` (in the following code this is `Logger`) and proceed as you used to.
- the components can not be built directly, but you need to use the builder pattern that was introduced in Log4j 2.x.

This sums up to the following code:

```java
Logger logger = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
final PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()//
                                          .withPattern("mylayoutpattern")
                                          .build();
final FileAppender appender = FileAppender.newBuilder()//
                                          .setLayout(layout)
                                          .withFileName("myFile")
                                          .withAppend(true)
                                          .build();
logger.addAppender(appender);
logger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Comment: Thanks you it works with org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.